# Get longitude and latitude with sign symbol

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

In my application i am getting longitude,latitude and store values in server.
When i print values directly i can get symbols(+ or -).After storing the values in float or NSString symbols are missing.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

```
currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    longtiude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    latitude= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}

 NSLog(@"New Lati%@, Long%@", latitude, longtiude);
```

Comment: You need to show code relevant to the problem. Show how you retrieve and display the problem values.

Comment: What output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: i am getting like 13.3332.but i need like +13.3332

Comment: Change the format specifier to `%+f` to force the + and - signs as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To always get a sign (`+` or `-`) prepended to the converted number, add `+` to the format specifier:

```
NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", 1.3, -1.3];
// Output: 1.300000 -1.300000
NSString *s2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+f %+f", 1.3, -1.3];
// Output: +1.300000 -1.300000
```